# Bootstrap3 Left Sidebar Right Toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to develop a web application with bootstrap.I have a left sidebar menu. I want that menu toggle from right while this page is opened from phone browser.
I want to create like this: https://formstone.it/

[image: 1]

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

My example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/gd39damu/3/

html code:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
    </div>

<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="navigation">

        <ul>
        <li><a  href="aa">aa</a></li>
        <li><a  href="bb">bb </a></li>
        <li><a  href="cc">cc</a></li>
        <li><a  href="dd">dd</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

</div> <!-- // Sidebar -->
</body>
```

css code:

```
 @import url('https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    .sidebar {
      background-color: #aaaaaa;
    }

    @media (min-width: 800px) {
      .sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        display: block;
      }

    .navigation {
        width: 240px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    }

    .navigation {
        background: #455a64;
        overflow-y: auto;
        padding: 30px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 800px){
        .sidebar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't understand what do you want to achieve? If you are trying to hide the side menu on mobile It is already done in your code, If anything else can you comment here?

Comment: Please, describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Sorry for my english I attached some picture , this might be help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used **jQuery toggle** and CSS to achieve this You can check the full code here on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QZ1XtcUB)

Comment: If anything else please comment here, If you are satisfied accept my answer and vote up thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using another jQuery Plugin for that, to make the menu smoother: http://ascott1.github.io/bigSlide.js/

It's a lightweight lib with around 1kb size.

Answer (score 0):

use **jQuery toggle** function with this

```
if ($(window).width() < 768){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an off-canvas overlay menu for Bootstrap.

Example: http://codeply.com/go/zyKyFfeUcH